# How to send text with telnet in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line

I would like to send some text to a port on my machine using `telnet` in the Mac OS X Terminal.

I start `telnet` using:

```
telnet localhost 8080
```

Then I type some text. Is that text send automatically or do I have to do something to send the text?

Comment: What is listening on port 8080? It is an address commonly used for web servers when the usual HTTP port 80 is unavailable. If it is a web server, you need to send a complete HTTP request, finished by two newlines (return characters, really). Normally, as explained by Laas below, a newline will trigger the sending of a line.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a simple Python server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 10  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send(data)  # echo
conn.close()
```

[Source](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication)

Save it as server.py, and run it `python server.py`.

Then try to connect using the terminal

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5005
```

Then just type anything and press <kbd>return</kbd>

The server print the data in the console and send it back to you.

That way, you'll know what you have to do to send data via telnet.

Answer (score 5):

When you typing the text in `telnet`, by default it operates in [*Linemode*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1184) which send the packets per line, so you just need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to send the command to the remote host (since terminal character processing on the client side). This is in order to reduce network traffic and it is very useful for long delay networks while typing the command line. If you need to send packets per character typed, then you need to switch to binary mode.

---

To test Telnet in *Linemode*, you can run the dummy server to be listening on the local port, e.g. by using `netcat` (install if needed):

```
nc -vl localhost 1234
```

then in another terminal connect to your server by:

```
telnet localhost 1234
```

and start entering some text to check when the data is received.

Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> (`^]`) and type `quit` to finish.

---

It is also possible to send data using Bash shell by the following command:

```
cat > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234
```

then start entering text. When finished, hit <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on what the remote end supports:

1. Newer [Line
   Mode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1184)
   where character processing is done
   locally while the remote only sends
   and receives control packets during
   typing and receives whole line when entering some end-of-line char (e.g hitting ENTER).
2. Character-at-a-time where
   each char is transmitted as it is
   typed.
3. Old line-at-a-time - fully
   completed lines are transmitted.

What the remote end does with the received input, depends on the remote end. Most server processes (HTTP, SMTP, POP, IMAP) tend to wait for end-of-line (EOL, newline) char before processing input. Some others may wait for end-of-file (EOF, ^D) before starting to process the input.

Answer (score 1):

After connecting using telnet hit the escape character (usually <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>). If you do not know your telnet escape key type `telnet` without parameters and it will display it, from there you can go back or use `open [ip] [port]`,
Once connected, you hit the escape key (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>)which will send you back to telnet where you can then type

> send [message]

If you'd like to get back to sending every key, just hit a random key that isn't a part of telnet's command list.

<sub>*P.S new versions will send one line whilst just typing instead of every key and the send command can only be used for preset telnet commands unless you're on windows in which case you can send strings via send as well.*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Try using `send` command after you've opened connection to the destination host.

```
send "some text"
```

For more information about `send` see `man telnet`

Comment: I tried, but I just get a new line when I press enter after it.

Comment: The `send` command is for sending special character sequences to remote machines, not random text. See the man page: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/telnet.1.html